# MATLAB: Selected title, xlabel, ylabel for Plots in a For Loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

In Matlab, I’m outputting a series of plots by a `for loop`.  The data iterating through the for loop to be plotted is constructed in a multidimensional matrix.  However I need the `title`, `xlabel`, and `ylabel` in the for loop to change its selected string for each iteration through the for loop.

Here is the code:

```
lat = [40 42 43 45 56]'
lon = [120 125 130 120 126]'
alt = [50 55 60 65 70]'
time = [1 2 3 4 5]'
position = cat(3, lat, lon, alt);

for k = 1:3
figure
plot(time, position(:,k),'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'b')
xlabel('Latitude Time');
ylabel('Latitude Mag');
title('Time v. Latitude');
end
```

How do I get the plots to output the labels in the for loop as:

First Iteration:

`xlabel` = Latitude Time
`ylabel` = Latitude Mag
`title` = Time v. Latitude

Second Iteration:

`xlabel` = Longitude Time
`ylabel` = Longitude Mag
`title` = Time v. Longitude

Third Iteration:

`xlabel` = Altitude Time
`ylabel` = Altitude Mag
`title` = Time v. Altitude

Comment: Make an cell array with labels and then index it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, use a cell array for your labels and index into it:

```
my_xlabels = {'Latitude Time';'Longitude Time';'Altitude Time'};
my_ylabels = {'Latitude Mag';'Longitude Mag';'Altitude Mag'};
my_titles = {'Time v. Latitude';'Time v. Longitude';'Time v. Altitude'};

for k = 1:3
   figure
   plot(time, position(:,k),'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'b')
   xlabel(my_xlabels{k});
   ylabel(my_ylabels{k});
   title(my_titles{k});
end
```